# Sorting products by catalog number in the frontend

Tags: sorting

Magento CE 1.9.1 - I have a custom attribute (Scott #) which essentially is a stamp catalog number. When the frontend sorts the display by Scott #, it was fine until I hit number 100. Now, it is putting catalog number 101 after number 1, rather than after number 99. How can I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: This sort is made by MySQL `ORDER BY`. You need natural sort but MySQL doesn't support it. That's why you have to make some workarounds on the MySQL query which is a little bit ugly. Or to sort the collection with php `natsort()`. Or the easiest solution - just add zeros before the numbers (i.e. 1 to become 001).

Comment: @michael great answer, please add it as an actual answer so OP can accept it if it works

Comment: @Sander Mangel, thank you. I added it as an answer but I don't think it's great. But I will be glad if it's a little helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This sort is made by MySQL `ORDER BY`. You need natural sort but MySQL doesn't support it. That's why you have to make some workarounds on the MySQL query which is a little bit ugly. Or to sort the collection with php `natsort()`. Or the easiest solution - just add zeros before the numbers (i.e. 1 to become 001).

Comment: Just tried adding the zeroes. It's a pain, but it works. Thanks!